# Change defaults Stacks icon settings?

Tags: macos, icons, stacks

Every time I create a new Stack, the Dock icon is automatically set to

Sort by: **Name**
Display as: **Stack**
View Content as: **Automatic**

and I have to change it to my preferred settings:

Sort by: **Kind**
Display as: **Folder**
View Content as: **List**

Can anyone tell me how to adjust the defaults display settings for new Stacks icons, please? I've searched and only found one instance of an answer (which was 'no' but I hope the replier was uninformed!).

Surely there must be a way to change these defaults?